# How can I solve the error of hmms installation?

Tags: python, pip

I want to install `hmms` with `pip` but got next output.

```
Collecting hmms
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/e4/c070c44ec8a391f6d5501316d1ed7615058f1fd365ff4ed65c9636d0bf62/hmms-0.1.tar.gz (412kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 419kB 120kB/s 
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-x2t1c_jd/hmms/setup.py", line 22, in <module>
    ext_modules=cythonize(glob.glob('hmms/*.pyx'), language_level=3, include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 886, in cythonize
    c_options = CompilationOptions(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 565, in __init__
    raise ValueError(message)
ValueError: got unknown compilation option, please remove: include_dirs

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-x2t1c_jd/hmms/
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this issue may be addressed on the github site for the HMMS module itself:

https://github.com/lopatovsky/HMMs/issues/4